# Linux - How to replace the last few characters of a file name with a string

Tags: linux, shell, unix, ksh

I have list of files and each file name ends with (+1) and I want to replace that (+1) of the filename with date

Ex:
 `ABC.DEF(+1)`

Looking for a simple solution which replaces the file name as below:

`ABC.DEF.20200127`

Comment: Use the `rename` command.

Comment: [so] is for programming questions, not questions about using or configuring Unix and its utilities. [unix.se] or [su] would be better places for questions like this.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure about the extension of your file, so I just considered .txt

```
for file in *.txt;   
do   
    mv "$file" "${file%????.txt}."`date +"%y%m%d"`""  
done
```

Comment: That doesn't replace `(+1)`, though.

Answer (score 0):

using rename:

```
rename "(+1)" "$(date +%Y%m%d)" *\(+1\)
```

Search for all files ending with (+1) and replace "(+1)" with the expanded, formatted date.